# Check Android device for available video capabilites?

Tags: android, video

Is there any easy way to check if an Android device can play a 1280 x 720 px MP4 H.264 Video, so that an app could gracefully fall back on a lower resolution version like 360 x 480 px or disable the video functionality? (The videos are embedded in the app, as they aren't very long.)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the physical resolution of the device using the following snippet:

```
WindowManager w = getWindowManager();
Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
int width = d.getWidth();
int height = d.getHeight();
```

---

EDIT:

Just checked the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html). The `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods are deprecated now. You will have to use [`getSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the idea; I could indeed check if the device is "large enough" to play 720p; although that could exclude devices with lower resolutions that are still higher than 480p and are capable of playing 720p. Tricky; looks like there is no real good solution though. :-(